# Como executar um comando no CMD ou no PowerShell, passando os comandos via C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, cmd, powershell, mysqldump

Preciso executar um comando no **CMD** que eu passe os parâmetros via C#
por exemplo:

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\mysqldump.exe" --column-statistics=0 -uroot -p1234 -hservidor -P3306 bancomysql  > D:\banco.sql
```

porém não quero executar esse comando via .bat ou eu mesmo digitar no **CMD**. Gostaria do C# passar esse comando e abrir o **CMD** ou o **Shell** para faze-lo.

Não sei como faria esse comando via **Shell** mas ouvi falar que seria mais fácil chamar o **Shell** via **C#**

Ou seja, no programa C# quero apertar um botão que chame esse comando e abra o **CMD** ou o **Shell** e rode esse comando por mim.

Comment: o caminho está certo ? normalmente eu utilizo mysqldump.exe de onde está instalado o mysql. não do workbench

Comment: sim o comando funciona diretamente de um .bat ou do CMD, mas não sei como fazer isso no C# diretamente

Comment: o C# eu ja não sei como ajudar, mas da uma olhada nesse link aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519328/executing-batch-file-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C# para abri e o CMD e rodar o comando:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C \"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\\mysqldump.exe\" --column-statistics=0 -uroot -p1234 -hservidor -P3306 bancomysql  > D:\banco.sql");
```

C# para abri o PowerShell:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("powershell.exe", "/C \"C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\\mysqldump.exe\" --column-statistics=0 -uroot -p1234 -hservidor -P3306 bancomysql  > D:\banco.sql");
```

O importante 'e o comando "/C" que copia toda a string a frente e cola no CMD/Shell.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, fazia tempo que eu estava tentando descobrir como fazer isso!!